# Making a new database if not existing

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm making a database checker if it exist. If not it should make a new database and tables.

My problem is I can't create the table, only the database.

```
private void Connect() throws Exception
  {
   try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///",
            "root", "");
    st = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "CREATE DATABASE dbproject2";
    //sql = "DROP DATABASE DBNAME";
    st.executeUpdate(sql);
    //con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///dbproject2","root", "");
    st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE tbl_admin(username varchar(200),password varchar(200),name varchar(200), PRIMARY KEY(username))");
    int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into tbl_admin values('admin','123456','Chris')");
    st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE tbl_emp(name varchar(200),department varchar(200),startTime time, PRIMARY KEY(name))");
    st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE tbl_records(cardNo varchar(100),holderNo varchar(100),holderName varchar(100),IODate date,IOTime time,IOGateNo varchar(100),IOGateName varchar(100),IOStatus varchar(100),departmentNo int(10), PRIMARY KEY(name))");

} catch (SQLException sqlException) {
    if (sqlException.getErrorCode() == 1007) {
        // Database already exists error
        Class.forName(Driver);      
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,pword);
        st = con.createStatement();
        st1 = con.createStatement();
    } else {
        // Some other problems, e.g. Server down, no permission, etc
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // No driver class found!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reconnect your new database and create new statement with these.
eg.

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///",
            "root", "");
    st = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "CREATE DATABASE dbproject2";
    //sql = "DROP DATABASE DBNAME";
    st.executeUpdate(sql);


con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///dbproject2","root", "");

    st = con.createStatement();


    st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE tbl_admin(username varchar(200),password varchar(200),name varchar(200), PRIMARY KEY(username))");
    int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into tbl_admin values('admin','123456','Chris')");
    st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE tbl_emp(name varchar(200),department varchar(200),startTime time, PRIMARY KEY(name))");
    st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE tbl_records(cardNo varchar(100),holderNo varchar(100),holderName varchar(100),IODate date,IOTime time,IOGateNo varchar(100),IOGateName varchar(100),IOStatus varchar(100),departmentNo int(10), PRIMARY KEY(name))");
```

Comment: this is not related your title question.but this is your SQL Syantax error not logic error. So recheck your SQL syantax and correct it please.

Comment: solved! just need to remove the use database statement